Div not showing after select
For some reason, I can display boxes and all, but everytime I try to display a DIV after a select has been chosen, nothing happens... Please advice.


$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = document.getElementById('showRef');
    divs.style.display = 'none';
    $('.selRef').on('change', function () {

        var refValid = (this.value == "Yes");
        if (refValid) {
            divs.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            divs.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <select id='selRef'
                required runat="server" clientidmode="Static" class="form-control selRef">
                <option value="No" selected>No</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="showRef" runat="server">
<div class="row mt-3">



Everytime I click or change the dropdownvalue, nothing happens...

We seem to be missing some context in your sample code here; for example, what is txtWeek?

Sorry mykaf, that part somehow got there, but that is a variable for another function. Just deleted it.

As it is here, your code seems to work correctly. Are there any errors in your dev console?  What steps have you taken to debug it? Could the runat="server" attribute be causing it?

The HTML shown is very invalid, and the element being shown/hidden has no content to observe.  In what way is specifically the code shown failing?  Can you clarify, or update the code snippet in the question to demonstrate?

runat="server" is usually associated with ASP.Net. If you're using that, it could be related to your issues.

@mykaf Bingo! just like that. It is the runat=server. But don't really understand why. Is there any documentation you can point me out to?

@HenryB runat="server" is generally an ASP.Net webforms construct. It's intended to submit the form back to the server so that the page can be re-rendered based on the updated user selections. This has the knock-on effect that any JS changes you have made to the DOM since the last postback will be lost. Frankly, WebForms is now very outdated. If you have any possibility to re-write this in a more modern framework, I would take it. If this is a codebase you need to maintain, research ASP.Net WebForms. and then look for a new position somewhere else.

@RoryMcCrossan thanks, man. Unfortunately, this is legacy code that needs some improvements, and can't really decide on that. Thanks for all your input, guys.

You are not so far from the solution. You just have to get the value of the select element with the .val() method.
Check out the code below :


$(document).ready(function () {
  const divs = document.getElementById('showRef');

  // you should define this style in html css
  //divs.style.display = 'none';

  const selRef = $('#selRef');
  selRef.on('change', function () {
    // if you log 'this.value', the script return the window object, this is not what you want
    // you have to get the value of the select element like this :
    const selRefValue = selRef.val();
    if (selRefValue === 'Yes') {
      divs.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
      divs.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
#title {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#showRef {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="title">
    <h1>Hello, this is a test!</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Here the code to test -->
  <select id='selRef' required>
    <option value="No" selected>No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>

  <div id="showRef" style="display: none"></div>
</body>



